# Prove that if a vector space $V$ has a basis of $n$ vectors, then every basis of $V$ must consist of exactly $n$ vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The proof in my textbook says:

Let $B_1$ be a basis of $ n $ vectors and $ B_2$ be any other basis of $V$.

(a)Because $ B_1$ is a basis and $B_2 $ is linearly independent, $B_2 $ has no more than n vectors.

(b)Because B$_2$ is a basis and $ B_1$ is linearly independent, $B_2$ has at least $n$ vectors. So $B_2$ has exactly $n $ vectors.

I understand (a) because I understand that if a vector space $V$ has a basis $ B = {b_1,...,b_n} $ then any set in $ V$ containing more than $n$ vectors must be linearly dependent.

But I don't understand the logic of (b).

SOS!

Comment: (b) is just the dual of (a). (a) states that B2 has no more vectors than B1 does. (b) states that B1 has no more vectors than B2 does.

Comment: What I am asking is how the logic follows for (b)

Comment: Another way would be to consider the position when $B_2$ has $m$ vectors. Then (a) is saying $m \le n$. By symmetry, (b) is saying $n \le m$ (just swap $B_1$ and $B_2$ in (a)).

Comment: There is another proof you can try . Proving $B_1$  is isomorphic to $B_2$ will prove $dimB_1 = dimB_2$.

Comment: It is the exact same logic both ways.  If $B_2$ has fewer vectors than $B_1$ then the vectors in $B_1$ must have a dependency (and $B_1$ couldn't be a basis).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any two bases of a finite dimensional vector space must have the same number of elements.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1208663/any-two-bases-of-a-finite-dimensional-vector-space-must-have-the-same-number-of)

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be a basis with $m$ elements and $B$ be a basis with $n$ elements.  Since both of them are basis of the vector space they have two properties i.e both of them span the vector space and both of them are linearly independent.  Take $A$ and use the property that it spans the vector space and take $B$ with the property that it is linearly independent. Now try to see that the cardinality of a spanning set is always $\geq$ to the cardinality of a spanning set. So from here you get $m\geq n$. Now reverse the roles of $A$ and $B$ to get $m\leq n$.

Answer (score 0):

The logic goes somehow like this: suppose $B_1$ has less elements than $B_2$. Lets say $B_1=\{b_1,\ldots,b_m\}$ and $B_2=\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ and $m<n$. Now you can replace $m$ elements in $B_2$ by $B_1$ and still have a set of linearly independent set of vectors. Say $B'=\{b_1,\ldots,b_m,v_{m+1},\ldots,v_n\}$.

But now since $B_1$ was a basis you have that $\sum a_i b_i=v_{m+1}$ for some $a_i$ in your field. But this means

$$ \sum_{i=1}^m a_i b_i -v_{m+1}=0, $$

contradicting that $B'$ is linearly independent.

Comment: I think your proof needs to be reworded since you're showing that your claim "Now you can replace $m$ ... and still have a LI set of vectors." is false. Properly written this is the correct argument.

Comment: @user347489 The statement is certainly not false. Its called the Steinitz exchange lemma: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz_exchange_lemma

Comment: You're right, however it's important to mention that the claim holds only up to reordering the elements of $B_2$. The way it's written this is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

$a.~~$ $B_2~$ has no more than cardinality $~B_1~$ vectors.

$b.~~$ $B_1~$ has no more than  cardinality $~B_2~$ vectors.

Same logic when you annihilate $~n~$.

Answer (score 0):

We can label the two bases whichever way round we like, so let's label them so that $|B_1| \le |B_2|$.

$B_1$ is a basis, so if $|B_2|$ were strictly greater than $|B_1|$ then $B_2$ would not be linearly independent. But $B_2$ is also a basis, so it must be linearly independent.

$\Rightarrow |B_1| = |B_2|$

Answer (score 0):

Let $B_{1}$ and $B_{2}$ two basis for the vector space $V$ suchs that $|B_{1}| = n$, $|B_{2}| = m$ with $m < n$ then $V \simeq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $V \simeq \mathbb{R}^{m}$ so by transitivity $\mathbb{R}^{n} \simeq \mathbb{R}^{m}$ which implies that $n = m$ but this is a contradiction.