# Proof that all basis holds same number of elements

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that the site has evidence of this statement, but I want to check my own proof.

$\textbf{Lemma 1}$
Uniqueness of the zero vector.

$\textbf{Proof}$: $\overline{\theta_1} = \overline{\theta_1} + \overline{\theta_2} = \overline{\theta_2} + \overline{\theta_1} = \overline{\theta_2}$

$\textbf{Lemma 2}$
For any vector there is a single inverse vector.

$\textbf{Proof}$: $-\overline{x_1} = -\overline{x_1} + \overline{\theta} = - \overline{x_1} + (\overline{x} -\overline{x_2}) = - \overline{x_1} + \overline{x} -\overline{x_2} = \overline{\theta} -\overline{x_2} = -\overline{x_2}$

$\textbf{Lemma 3}$
The product of any vector by the neutral element of the additive group of the field is the zero vector.

$\textbf{Proof}$: $0 \cdot \overline{x} = 0 \cdot \overline{x} + \overline{\theta} = 0 \cdot \overline{x} + (\overline{x} - \overline{x}) = \overline{x}(0 + 1) - \overline{x} = \overline{x} - \overline{x} = \overline{\theta}$

$\textbf{Lemma 4}$:
The product of the zero vector on any field element is equal to the zero vector.

$\textbf{Proof}$: $\alpha\cdot\overline{\theta} = \alpha\cdot(0\cdot\overline{x}) = (\alpha \cdot 0)\cdot \overline{x} = 0\cdot \overline{x}$

$\textbf{Lemma 5}$:
If $\lambda \neq 0$ and $\overline{x} \neq \overline{\theta}$ the $\lambda\cdot\overline{x}\neq\overline{\theta}$.

$\textbf{Proof}$: Suppose it is not a true and we can have $\lambda\cdot\overline{x} = \overline{\theta}$, where $\lambda\neq 0$ and $\overline{x}\neq\overline{\theta}$. $\overline{x} = 1\cdot\overline{x} = (\frac{1}{\lambda}\cdot\lambda)\overline{x} = \frac{1}{\lambda} \cdot (\lambda\cdot \overline{x}) = \frac{1}{\lambda}\cdot \overline{\theta} = \overline{\theta}$ -- contradiction.

$\textbf{Lemma 6}$:
In any set of linearly independent vectors, there is no zero vector.

$\textbf{Proof}$: $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i\overline{x_i} = \overline{\theta}$ and one of the $\exists \overline{x_j}\in \{\overline{x_n}\}, \overline{x_j} = \overline{\theta}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\lambda_j$ can be $\neq 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\{\overline{x_n}\}$ -- linear dependent.

$\textbf{Lemma 7}$
The representation of the zero vector in any basis is unique.

$\textbf{Proof}$: Assume that it is not true: $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i\overline{x_i} = \overline{\theta}$, where one of the $\lambda_j \neq 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\lambda_j\overline{x_j} = 0$, but by Lemma 5 and Lemma 6 it is impossible.

$\textbf{Theorem}$: All basis holds same number of elements.

$\textbf{Proof}$: If we have two basis $\{\overline{e_n}\}$ and $\{\overline{e'_m}\}$, where $m > n$. So we can represent the vectors of the second basis by vectors of the first basis: $\overline{e'_k} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{ik}\overline{e_i}$, where $k=1,\cdots,m$ and for any vector $\overline{x}$ in this space will be true that $\overline{x} = \sum_{k=1}^{m}\lambda_k\overline{e'_k} = \sum_{k=1}^{m}\lambda_k\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_{ik}\overline{e_i} =\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\sum_{k=1}^{m}\lambda_k \alpha_{ik})\overline{e_i} $. The zero vector $\overline{\theta}$ has the unique representation in the basis $\{\overline{e_i}\}$, $\overline{\theta} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}0_i\overline{e_i}$. Therefore, the condition $\sum_{k=1}^{m}\lambda_k\overline{e'_k} = 0$ is equivalent to system of linear equations for $\lambda_k$: $\sum_{k=1}^{m}\lambda_k\alpha_{ik} = 0$, where $i=1,\cdots,n$. Since the number of $\{\lambda_k\}=m$  is greater than the number of equations $=n$, this system has a non-zero solution. This contradicts to the Lemma 7.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any two bases of a finite dimensional vector space must have the same number of elements.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1208663/any-two-bases-of-a-finite-dimensional-vector-space-must-have-the-same-number-of)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reformulate Lemma 2, since you only proof the uniqueness, not the existence.
In the proof of Lemma 2 it's pretty circuitous that you use these minus signs. Just name the two inverse vectors $x_1$ and $x_2$.

In the proof of Lemma 5 you should formulate the assumption and the contradiction and in the proof of Lemma 6 you're mixing up formulas and sentences.

The proof of Lemma 7 is not correct. You can only follow $$\lambda_j\cdot \overline{x_j}=0$$ from comparing the two representations, if you use that the representation of each basis vector is unique, which uses the assertion you want to proof.

Your proof of the theorem is correct, if Lemma 6 and 7 hold to be true, since there is a solution, hence for the under determined system there must be infinitely many.

Comment: Existence in Lemma 2 posululated by axiom of vector space. About Lemma 7, you are right, yes, the uniqueness of the representation of the zero vector simply follows from the definition of a basis in which each element of space is represented uniquely

Comment: About Lemma 2: I know you don't have to prove existence, my comment was just about the formulation of the Lemma.
Yeah, you get the uniqueness of the representation of $\theta$ by the definition of the linear independence.